# Magento 2.2.2 Prodcut quanity, color and sku not displaying under custom tab

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.2, tabs

I have created a **custom tab** on **product pag**e and tried to display **product attributes** under this tab, i am only able to display price only.

I have tried like this

```
<?php
   $product = $block->getProduct();
?>

<h1>
   <?php echo $product->getData('quantity'); ?>
   <?php echo $product->getData('color'); ?>
   <?php echo $product->getData('price'); ?>
</h1>
```

**Quantity**, **Color** and **Sku** not displaying

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getCustomAttribute('your_attribute')` for geting an attribute value, see below, it is with validation:

```
if ($product->getCustomAttribute('your_attribute') !== null) {
   echo $product->getCustomAttribute('your_attribute')->getValue();
}
```

Comment: I just implemented your code. The product quantity is 1 but its not displaying.

Comment: I tested and it works, but you must set the show on frontend that attributes from admin panel.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LTndDwVw24gkbnQT3_ERx4aEGpaed915/view

Comment: After that, you can refresh the cache or flush cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to fetch product attribute value in tabs:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getPrice(), 'price') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what type of attribute any of them are you have a different way of getting the output, check `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml` for an example, this is the "More information" tab content with all the `Visible on frontend` attributes

Answer (score 0):

To get the quantity

```
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

For attribute like color etc,

```
$product->getAttributeText('color'); OR  echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this Way ...
For Quantity and Sku, use this method..

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<h1>
  <?php echo $product->getQuantity(); ?>
  <?php echo $product->getSku()(); ?>
  /* This For your color Attribute */ 
  <?php echo $product->getData('color');
</h1>
```